# How to append the columns in the same column in different rows which endswith similar names

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert dataframe which looks the following :

```
time | 0.id | 0.a | 0.b | 1.id | 1.a | 1.b |...

00:00| abc  | 0a  | 0b  | bcd  | 1a  | 1b |...
```

to the following:

```
time  | id  | a  | b |...

00:00 | abc | 0a | 0b|...
00:00 | bcd | 1a | 1b|...
```

I am using python and the dataframe is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: Unfortunately, Stack overflow is not a code-writing or a homework service. What have you tried so far, based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I have tried "melt" and " groupby / concat " but unable to achieve the result that I need.

Comment: d = {'0.id':'id', 
'0.a' :'a',
'0.b' :'b'}
test.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([*zip(map(d.get, test), test)])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `wide_to_long` after flipping the column names so the `stubnames` are correct.

```
df.columns = ['_'.join(x[::-1]) for x in df.columns.str.split('.')]
stubs = pd.unique([x[0] for x in df.columns.str.split('_') if x[0] != 'time'])

pd.wide_to_long(df, i='time', stubnames=stubs, sep='_', j='num').reset_index(1, drop=True)

#        id   a   b
#time              
#00:00  abc  0a  0b
#00:00  bcd  1a  1b
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your time to reply to this. Im getting an error saying "ValueError: the id variables need to uniquely identify each row"

Comment: also tried  "pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=stubs, i='time', j='num').reset_index(drop=True).sort_values(['time']).dropna(how='any')"

Comment: this worked --- "pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(),
                          i = ['time','index'],
                          stubnames=stubs,
                          sep='_',
                          j='num')
          .reset_index(1, drop=True)
          .dropna(how='any')" thanks !!!